# Android Listview help

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a `ListView` like this. I played around with `ListView` control but still no luck. If any one could tell me how to do this or give me a link to a sample code highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Need to be more specific on what you are trying to get the ListView to do that it does not do.

Comment: I am interested in creating a ListView with with shadowing like above. I played around little and realized when i remove android:cacheColorHint overlaying shadows disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like simple listview with background color and added order numbers. you know already how to set the color. if it comes to numbers I'd use SimpleCursorAdapter to create list and ViewBinder to add numbers

Answer (score 0):

use

android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" in your list view, if it is color thing that you are worrying about.